# Some downvotes are missing from the reputation tab?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes, profile-page

Not so long ago I could see in my reputation tab which questions/answers have been downvoted, but it seems now this feature is gone. Is it me or is this a new policy which I'm not aware of?

Comment: By "rating list", you refer to [the reputation tab of your profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/121097/user26857?tab=reputation)?

Comment: I see that a lot of your downvoted answers were downvoted so that the questions that you answered, which were subsequently closed, would go through auto-deletion. This does not mean your answer was bad, but that people thought the question lacked context. (I question this procedure, because many of these questions are good questions otherwise, and good answers get removed from the site.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: I see downvotes received in other profiles, so it seems that robjohn's comment is most of the answer to your question: the posts that have been downvoted were deleted, and that hides them from the reputation tab. If you check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of the page, I think _you_ will see the removed posts and associated downvotes in your profile.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I'd have posted an answer to such a question, then this would have been upvoted (and then I'd have lost 10 points), or not upvoted (and then I won't lose any point), or downvoted (and then I'd have get the points back).

Comment: The two points you lost, you lost because [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684524/give-an-example-of-a-function-f-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-with-the-pr) (sorry, you need 442 points more before you can see it), which you had an accepted edit suggestion on in February was deleted an hour ago, so you lost the two points for the edit.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. So, this kind of things can't be seen on the reputation tab. (Please post your last comment as an answer. Maybe other users wonder(ed) about this.)

Comment: I think you can see them at 10k, there would be an entry $-2$ (removed) with a link to the removed question. I'm not sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well from the comments it seems this happens only for the deleted by the system questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to lose 2 points: receiving a downvote, or losing a +2 for suggested edit. When you receive a downvote, it's recorded in the reputation history as such, and links to corresponding posts are provided. Here's an example from mine:

[image: example]

Selecting the checkbox "Show removed posts" will also show the votes you received on the posts that were subsequently deleted. (Note that votes on deleted posts do not affect reputation.)

On the other hand, the loss of the +2 bonus for a suggested edit is more difficult to track down, but this does not happen often.

Comment: And where one exactly can find "Show removed posts"?

Comment: At the very bottom of the /reputation tab of your profile.